# Change (horizontal) position of minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cv, tabto

I'm building my resume in Latex, and this is my first Latex project. I've used the `tabto` package to move some points to a certain horizontal position. Now, I'm trying to move my address at the top to the same position. However, no matter what I'm doing, I can't figure out how to move the minipage to a specific horizontal position using `tabto`. Any ideas?

[image]

**resume.tex**

```
\documentclass{my_resume}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\contactname{My Name} \\                % name
\noindent\begin{minipage}[ht]{.48\textwidth}
  \contactinfo
  {tel:+010000000000}                           % phone link (with int'l code)
    {000-000-0000}                              % phone display text
  {mailto:user@host.com}                        % email link
    {user@host.com}                             % email display text
  {https://user.com}                            % web link
    {user.com}                                  % web display text
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[ht]{.48\textwidth}
  \contactaddress
  {Street}                                      % address line 1 (house and street)
  {City, State}{Zip}                            % address line 2 (city, state, and zip)
  {Coutnry}                                     % address line 3 (country)
\end{minipage}%

\section{{\faBriefcase} Experience}
\placeandlocation{Company1}{City, State} \\
\titleandyears{Title}{Date - Date} \\
Duties \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item2
  \item Item3
  \item Item4
\end{itemize}
Accomplishments \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item2
  \item Item3
  \item Item4
\end{itemize}
\bigskip
\placeandlocation{Company2}{City, State} \\
\titleandyears{Title}{Date - Date} \\
Duties \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item2
  \item Item3
  \item Item4
\end{itemize}
Accomplishments \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item2
  \item Item3
  \item Item4
\end{itemize}

\section{{\faGraduationCap} Education}
\placeandlocation{University}{City, State} \\
Major:~\majorminor{Major}{Date - Date}\\
Minor:~\majorminor{Minor}{}\\
GPA:~~~~4.00/4.00 \\
Accomplishments \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item1
  \item Item2
  \item Item3
  \item Item4
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**my_resume.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{my_resume}
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}       % to left/right align items
\RequirePackage{enumitem}                 % to change spacing between lists
  \setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,topsep=0pt} % set some list defaults
\RequirePackage[letterpaper,portrait,margin=0.75in]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage[oldstylenums}
\RequirePackage[final]{microtype}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}                 % to format the title
\RequirePackage{color}                    % to define specific colors
  \definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{6,69,173}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}                 % to make clickable URLs
  \hypersetup{
      colorlinks=true,
      linkcolor=darkblue,                 % color of internal links
      urlcolor=darkblue,                  % color of external links
  }
\RequirePackage{tabto}                    % for aligning text

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FontAwesome               %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{fontspec}                 % to add fonts
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome.ttf}      % place FontAwesome.ttf in the same folder
  \def\faMobile{\FA \symbol{"F10B}}
  \def\faPhone{\FA \symbol{"F095}}
  \def\faPhoneSquare{\FA \symbol{"F098}}
  \def\faEnvelope{\FA \symbol{"F0E0}}
  \def\faHome{\FA \symbol{"F015}}
  \def\faGlobe{\FA \symbol{"F0AC}}
  \def\faBriefcase{\FA \symbol{"F0B1}}
  \def\faGraduationCap{\FA \symbol{"F19D}}
  \def\faMapMarker{\FA \symbol{"F041}}

\newcommand{\rightsidetab}{4.9in}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Contact info              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\contactname}[1]{
  {\raggedright\Huge{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\contactinfo}[6]{
  \raggedright  
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} c l}
    {\faPhone} & \href{#1}{#2} \\
    {\faEnvelope} & \href{#3}{#4} \\
    {\faGlobe} & \href{#5}{#6}
  \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\contactaddress}[4]{
  \raggedright{\faHome} {#1} \\
   {#2} {#3} \\
   {#4}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sections                  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright}
  {}{0em}
  {}
  [\titlerule]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Experience specific stuff %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\placeandlocation}[2]{
  {\raggedright\bf{{#1}} \tabto{\rightsidetab}{\faMapMarker} {#2}}
}
\newcommand{\titleandyears}[2]{
  {\raggedright\textit{#1} \tabto{\rightsidetab} {#2}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Education specific stuff  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\majorminor}[2]{
  {\raggedright\textit{#1} \tabto{\rightsidetab} {#2}}
}
```

Comment: FYI, there are a few CV documentclasses out there. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae

Comment: I couldn't even get the tabto package to load without an emergency stop.